Is it possible to view the output of systemctl status by user, where that user is the name of the user that the service file process runs as?
I have created a series of systemd service files which run some processes on a Linux server.
Each service file looks the same, but with different log file names, process names, and service descriptions.
[Unit]
Description=Process 1 service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
User=processuser
Group=processuser
WorkingDirectory=/var/log/process-group
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/process-group/process-1.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/process-group/process-1.error.log
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/process-group/.venv/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/process-group/process_1.py

[Install]
WantedBy=land_registry_data.target

The target, which is used to create a group from the service files, is defined as follows.
[Unit]
Description=Process Group
Wants=process_1.service process_2.service ...
After=process_1.service process_2.service ...

These services run with the user and group set to processuser. This user and group has been created as follows.
sudo groupadd processuser
sudo useradd -r -s /bin/false -g processuser processuser

I thought it should be possible to view the status of all the services as a group.
I tried a few approaches:

Using systemctl --user option

sudo systemctl --user processuser status

This produces an error message Unknown command verb processuser

Using systemctl -M

sudo systemctl --user -M processuser@ status
● processuser@
    State: degraded
    Units: 142 loaded (incl. loaded aliases)
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 2 units
    Since: Tue 2024-05-28 21:47:30 BST; 5s ago
  systemd: xxx
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-989.slice/user@989.service
           ├─init.scope
           │ ├─3071922 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
           │ └─3071923 "(sd-pam)"
           └─session.slice
             └─dbus.service
               └─3071942 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only

This doesn't appear to print anything useful. It is as if the services are not running under the user processuser. I am not totally sure if this is expected or not.

Using the xxx.target file:

sudo systemctl status xxx.target

This reports that the target is active but says nothing about the underlying individual services.
Ideally I am looking for a way to list whether or not all of the services which are part of this group are running. I thought I could perhaps do that using the user/group information or using the xxx.target systemd file. Is there a systemd command to do this?
